# Cronjob to run hourly and email result

Tags: bash

Let me tell what I've done first

```
#update.sh
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/freshclam
maldet -b -a /home
```

Another Script

```
#doandmail.sh
./update.sh > mail.txt

SUBJECT="Shell Script"
EMAIL="myemail@gmail.com"
EMAILMESSAGE="mail.txt"

/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
```

When I run doandmail.sh using `./doandmail.sh` an email with result was sent. I've added this line in cron `@hourly /custom/doandmail.sh` and I got blank email every hour.

I'm fully novice, need your advice to solve.

Comment: have you try full path to `update.sh` and `mail.txt` ? Maybe cron run script with different folder as "current working folder".

Comment: update.sh, mail.txt and doandmail.sh are in same directory, /custom/, and in crontab, I've added @hourly /custom/doandmail.sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line before the interpreter directive - before the `#!` line - is wrong but may not be your problem. The `#!` is only special as the first two characters of a executable file, and identifies what program should open it (`/bin/bash` in this case).  The shells will tend to try to interpret scripts by defaulting to themselves, but this isn't reliable - especially for non-sh scripts.

Secondly, http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful

So in `/custom/update`

```
#!/bin/bash
#  update

/usr/bin/freshclam
maldet -b -a /home
```

then run: `chmod +x /custom/update`

In `./doandmail`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#  doandmail

SUBJECT="Shell Script"      # these don't need to be uppercase
EMAIL="myemail@gmail.com"   # ...though it doesn't hurt anything
EMAILMESSAGE="mail.txt"     # usually only exported variable are upper.

/custom/update | /bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL"   # no need for a tmp file.
```

Then: `chmod +x doandmail`

When your `crontab` runs, it won't have the same directory you're thinking, or even the same environment you might expect, unless you set them explicitly.  It's most likely breaking on the `./update`... line in `doandmail`.  Hence the `/custom/update` above.

In your crontab:

```
@hourly /custom/doandmail
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say that the problem is in ./update.sh > mail.txt

Cron can be funny with paths - make these be absolute paths and try again.

Comment: +1 but also `doandmail.sh` is pretty redundant because Cron sends you the output as email anyhow. (Granted, it would be useful to be able to set a useful subject line, but that is hardly the case here anyway.) You can override the recipient by setting `MAILTO` in your `crontab`.